# What's a good microphone around $100-$200 that can be both used for recording audio for game development and for streaming?

Tags: microphone, gameaudio, streaming

I'm planning to start Twitch-streaming the development of the game I'm currently working on this weekend. I'm looking for a microphone that records with good quality (currently I just have the microphone built into my Siberia V2 headset).

If possible I'd also like to be able to use it for recording stuff for the game.

I've looked at the Yeti Blue but it seems like it might pick up the keyboard quite a bit. Perhaps that's an issue with all high quality microphones?

Comment: Look for a directional mic instead of an omni-directional mic, if most of your sound is in front of the mic.

Comment: It's not clear to me what kind of audio material ou're trying to record with the mic (e.g. speac, live musi, environmental sounds or something else...)

Answer (score 1):

Snag an sm58 or anything of similar type.  I've seen a bunch of tutorials where the instructor has one hooked up to a mic stand and right near their mouth.  Works great.  Obviously the easier thing would be to get one with a usb out.

Something like this
http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=751977&gclid=CjwKEAjw6_q5BRCOp-Hj-IfHwncSJABMtDaiYWDrJT2sAiARDW9-qHKjaISWn_GG0P3_QalgSMWQmRoCOdnw_wcB&is=REG&ap=y&m=Y&c3api=1876%2C92051678762%2C&Q=&A=details

You need some sort of stand for it tho.  But this is a very simple and clean option